# How does work mongodb with nested structures?

Tags: mongodb

For example I have object as:

```
 var nested_object_1 = {
       id : 1,
       power: true,
       name : "Ok",
       value: nested_object_2
    }

    var car= {
      id : 1,
      name : "Car",
      value: nested_object_1
    }

    var nested_object_2 = {
      id : 1,
      name : "Hola"
    }
```

How can I update object `nested_object_2` that is located in another object?

Need I iterate all nested objects in loops?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained what you need to update in the document. Based on limited information:

The way I look at the document is

```
var car= {
  id : 1,
  name : "Car",
  value: {
    id : 1,
    power: true,
    name : "Ok",
    value: {
      id : 1,
      name : "Hola"
    }
  }
}
```

You don't have to iterate, just specify the complete path to the variable in update function

```
var updatednestedobject2 = {id:1, name: 'Updated Hola'};
db.CarCollection.findOneAndUpdate({id:1}, {$set: {'value.value': updatednestedobject2}})
```

Comment: Okay, but how to update when I dont know external id? `findOneAndUpdate({id:1}`?